# Django - ModelForm save creating object with null fields?

Tags: python, django, forms

So I have a model with 6 attributes and then a model form with 3 attributes that is used to fill in 3 of those 6 attributes. One of those 3 attributes is an imagefield so I believe I need to use form.save() to save the image to the upload_to location. However, when I try and use form.save() it immediately creates an object with missing fields and fails. How can I create one object and upload the image with form.save()? I also could be misunderstanding the user of form.save() though. Without form.save() the image is not uploaded to the upload_to location.

My code is below....

Models.py

```
class Posting(models.Model):
    textbook = models.ForeignKey(Textbook)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='postingpics/%Y/%m/%d', default="../../static/textchange/nophoto.jpg")
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('date_posted')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.textbook)

    def was_posted_recently(self):
        return self.post_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_posted_recently.admin_order_field = 'post_date'
    was_posted_recently.boolean = True
    was_posted_recently.short_description = 'Posted recently'
```

Forms.py

```
class PostCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posting
        fields = ('price', 'condition', 'image')
    CHOICES = (('New', 'New'), ('Like New', 'Like New'), ('Used', 'Used'), ('Usable', 'Usable'))
    price = forms.DecimalField()
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def addposting(request, uisbn):
    form = PostCreate(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    # Get textbook with isbn equal to usibn
    ltextbook = Textbook.objects.filter(isbn = uisbn)
    text = ltextbook[0]
    curuser = request.user

    if form.is_valid() and request.POST:
        condition = request.POST.get('condition')
        price = request.POST.get('price')
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        if image:
            if (not (Posting.objects.filter(Q(user = curuser) & Q(textbook = text)))):
                print("one")
                print("two")
                new = Posting(textbook = text, user = curuser, post_date = datetime.now(), condition=condition, price=price, image = image)
                print("three")
                form.save()
                print("bw")
                new.save()
                print("four")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/' + uisbn)
        else:
            if (not (Posting.objects.filter(Q(user = curuser) & Q(textbook = text)))):
                new = form.save()
                new = Posting(textbook = text, user = curuser, post_date = datetime.now())
                new.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/' + uisbn)

    return render_to_response(
        'textchange/addposting.html',
        locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

The print statements in Views.py were just for testing and experimenting.

Edit:

Here is the error:

IntegrityError at /results/9781439820643/posting/add
null value in column "post_date" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (132, New, 23.00, null, null, null, postingpics/2015/09/18/office_WnbptWi.png).

Comment: the field `post_date` is not in your form but it is required in the model that you try to save. You can delete the post_date field, or make sure it is filled (add `auto_now=True`).

Comment: what's the use of a ModelForm if you redefine the fields?

Comment: Im missing textbook_id, user_id, and post_date from the form though. So I need to do form.save() to upload the image but I need to append those 3 attributes to the save

Comment: @Pynchia I was just using the modelform to make saving the imagefield easy

Comment: @Pynchia Are modelforms only supposed to be used when you're entering all the model information?

Comment: No, you have full control over the form and can cherry-pick the fields you need and add others if you need them. Models and forms go through separate validation. Please read the [official django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: Given the error thrown, I believe @allcaps nailed it in the first comment :) My comments are optional

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I just need to make a custom form.save()

Comment: @joe Yes, a custom Form.save will work. But it is one of many things you can do. You can also add a model Model.save OR a use a pre save signal OR  make `pub_date` not required OR add the field to the form (the value is filled by the user) OR drop post_date from your model OR add an `auto_now_add` attribute to the field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add . All have some advantages and disadvantages. The `auto_now_add` seems to make the most cense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just not filling required  fields so either you will fill them all or, you can just change model fields to

```
textbook = models.ForeignKey(Textbook,required=false)
condition = models.CharField(max_length = 200,required=false)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,required=false)
user = models.ForeignKey(User,required=false)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='postingpics/%Y/%m/%d', default="../../static/textchange/nophoto.jpg",required=false)
post_date = models.DateTimeField('date_posted',required=false)
```